# How to display comment using FOSCommentBundle Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, foscommentbundle

I want to integrate comments in my web page. So that I used the Symfony2.3 Bundle `FosCommentBundle`. I followed the  steps indicated in the Bundle documentation , but in the fourth step nothing happens on the generated page and I get ajax 500 Internal error:

```
http://127.0.0.1/ecomerce/web/app.php/api/threads/1/comments?permalink=http%253A%252F%252F127.0.0.1%252Fecomerce%252Fweb%252Fapp.php
```

I didn't find plenty of tutorials about this bundle.
Is there any js file I have to include it on my page to make it works?

Comment: pls check app/logs/prod.log or request http://127.0.0.1/ecomerce/web/app_dev.php/api/threads/1/comments?permalink=http%253A%252F%252F127.0.0.1%252Fecomerce%252Fweb%252Fapp.php and post the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by clearing the cache.